# Import and parse an xml file without FileOutputStream

Tags: java

Consider the code fragment that I have at the moment which works and the right elements are found and placed into my map:

```
  public void importXml(InputSource emailAttach)throws Exception {
      Map<String, String> hWL = new HashMap<String, String>();

      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();     
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

      Document doc = db.parse(emailAttach);

      FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("temp.xml");

      OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(fos,"UTF-8");
      //  Transform to XML UTF-8 format
      TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();  
      t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
      os.close();
      fos.close();

      doc = db.parse(new File("temp.xml"));

      NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Email");
      Element eE=(Element)nl.item(0);
      int ctr=eE.getChildNodes().getLength();
      String sNName;
      String sNValue;
      Node nTemp;
      for (int i=0;i<ctr;i++){
         nTemp=eE.getChildNodes().item(i);
         sNName=nTemp.getNodeName().toUpperCase().trim();
         if (nTemp.getChildNodes().item(0)!=null) {
            sNValue=nTemp.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue().trim();
            hWL.put(sNName,sNValue); 
         }
      }
 }
```

However I prefer not to create a temp file first after converting the data to UTF-8 and parsing from the temp file. Is there anyway I can do this?

I've tried using a ByteArrayOutputStream in place of OutputStreamWriter, and calling toString() on the ByteArrayOutputStream as such:

```
doc = db.parse(bos.toString("UTF-8");
```

But then my Map ends up being empty.

Comment: Ron, could you tell why you do this identity transformation in the first place? In other words what's going wrong if you just use `Document doc = db.parse(emailAttach);` to collect your `hWL`? I expect that high-level Java XML API should isolate you from the low-level encoding details without this additional transformation.

Comment: I'd rather do that as well but this is a revamp project and the old source code has a section where it converts the email attachment to UTF-8 first. I can't tell you why this is necessary since I don't even have test data so it would be safer for me to leave that handling in. I guess there is a chance the XML email attachments may have non-English characters. Unfortunately, the old logic includes saving a UTF-8 converted version of the attachment on the file system before reading in to be parsed again but this is a intermediary step I believe I can try to eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

From the API docs (the ability of its meticulous studying is a valuable asset for any programmer) - the parse method with the String argument seems to take something different from what you feed to it:

> Document   parse(String uri)
>   Parse the content of the given URI as an XML document and return a new DOM >Document object.

This might be your friend:

> db.parse ( new ByteArrayInputStream( bos.toByteArray()));

Answer (score 0):

Update
@user2496748 sorry I should have searched for the API but instead I was looking at the source code through a decompiler which tells me the parameter is arg0 instead of uri. Big difference.

I think I understand stream readers/writers and byte to char or vice versa a little more now.

After some review I was able to simply my code to this and achieve what I wanted to do. Since I am able to get the email attachment as a InputSource:

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();     
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

  emailAttach.setEncoding("UTF-8");

  Document doc = db.parse(emailAttach);
```

Works as well and tested with non-english characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write and re-read and re-parse the transformed document. Just change this:

```
t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

to this:

```
DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);
doc = (Document)result.getNode();
```

and then continue from after your present `doc = db.parse(new File("temp.xml"));`.